# Non-breaking parentheses?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

In the footer of a flexible-layout website I've noticed that IE tends to line-wrap on parenthesis characters (in a phone number in this case).  Is there a visually equivalent non-breaking parenthesis, in a similar vein to non-breaking spaces and non-breaking hyphens, that I can use instead?

Comment: Maybe you could look for non-ASCII parentheses that you can use. I'm not sure if suitable ones exist, but that could be an option I guess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
.phone{
    white-space: nowrap;
}

<p>Call Customer Support at <span class="phone">+34 (947) 12 34 56 78</span> for further enquiries.</p>
```

You can do many other things (from `<nobr>` tag to certain Unicode chars) but they aren't as cross-browser as this.

Comment: This is a good practical solution, however, I'm specifically looking for a pure html version, for non-css users (accessibility is a priority).

Comment: This is a minor cosmetic issue. Having an line break in the middle of a phone number is not an accessibility issue.

Comment: @David Dorward That's not the point I was making.  My priority is to provide as similar an experience as possbile without CSS.  Also, I disagree, I think it *is* an accessibility barrier.

Comment: You can use `<nobr>` as this answer suggests if you don't want CSS, but I can't think of a single browser alive that doesn't support CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately this prevents breaking on everything.  It may solve the OPs problem, but I have the specific problem from the title;  I need to stop IE from breaking on parentheses, but still break on white-space.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue with a plural treatment like "user(s)" where IE breaks the word after the R. You should be able to use the word joiner character (&#x2060;), but in my test with IE11, only the deprecated zero-width non-breaking space character worked:

```
user&#xFEFF;(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem; here is a solution which worked:

```
The number to call is: (423)&nbsp;276&mdash;0000
```

According to the Unicode Standard (specifically, UAX #14), a line break
is not permitted before or after a no-break space.  Therefore, the &nbsp; prevents the browser from line-breaking on the parentheses.  In either case, it doesn't hurt to have a space between the area code and the phone number.