# How to prevent a line break between text elements where there is no whitespace

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to keep two text elements from being split apart by line breaks in an epub file (xhtml and css).

Example:

> This is a line of text that reaches the end of the display and <sup>[12]</sup>what I don't want is for that superscripted part to be separated from the next word.

Which ends up looking like this:

> This is a line of text that reaches the end of the display and <sup>[12]</sup>
>   what I don't want is for that superscripted part to be separated
>   from the next word.

I would like it to look like this:

> This is a line of text that reaches the end of the display and
>   <sup>[12]</sup>what I don't want is for that superscripted part to be
>   separated from the next word.

Some software on my pc keeps the superscripted `<sup>[12]</sup>` and the `what` together, but my Sony ebook reader doesn't. Other e-readers may do the same. I'd like it to consistently keep the superscripted part together with the next word and avoid a line break between them.

I've looked at quite a few similar questions, but can't find anything that matches this problem.

I'd prefer to deal with this problem via css, rather than editing a huuuuuge bunch of files by adding tags throughout it, which would be further complicated by the fact that the word after each superscripted part can be any word, ruling out a simple search and replace.

In a similar vein, I'd also like to extend the "keeping things together" bit when the next word is "I" or "A" or "a" or any short 2-letter word, so a sentence like

> bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <sup>[35]</sup>in the simplest way imaginable.

would line break in either of these ways:

> bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <sup>[35]</sup>in the
>   simplest way imaginable.
>
> bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
>   <sup>[35]</sup>in the simplest way imaginable.

but NOT break like:

> bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <sup>[35]</sup>
>   in the simplest way imaginable.
>
> bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <sup>[35]</sup>in
>   the simplest way imaginable.

Is there perhaps a way to set some margin property or whatever so that any superscript tag must be a minimum distance removed from the right hand margin, or else it will be moved to the next line? I could then set that minimum distance to encompass the tagged part plus an additional 2 or 3 character widths.

Something like the `page break after : avoid;` property but working at the line (not page) level would be great. Or even an `orphan: 5;` type property for lines might do the trick.

I'm thinking (and hoping) that both the problems I've outlined above can have one and the same solution.

Comment: Can you take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712716/non-breaking-parentheses? If I understood your question, this is almost the same problem. I like the <span> solution, but the <nobr> should work as well on modern browsers.. I don't think there's any way to do this using plain css and without adding any tags..

Comment: I had a look at that page, but the <span> solution is not practical as there are far too many lines to edit, which I can't do with a simple search and replace because the span must encompass the next word (which varies from line to line).

Comment: Great, I just ran into the 5-minute limit for editing comments. Here's the next bit I wanted to add: I'd also like to avoid adding so much extra bulk to the file. The whitespace: nowrap; may do the trick, although it requires me to add a space or &nbsp; after each [n], and to keep the [n] with the next 3 character minimum will require a manual search and replace through thousands of lines. I'm still hopeful of a more elegant solution using css.

Comment: "will require a manual search and replace" - Why manual? That is a perfect example for a task that can be automated.

Comment: @Pumbaa80: yes you'd think so, but although I can search with wildcards (regular expressions) I can't replace the found terms with extra elements either side while leaving the wildcarded items unchanged.

Comment: @Pumbaa80:  Hmm, you're right, this can be done with regular expressions. The web page I was reading to figure out how to use regular expressions was so carefully worded as to rather hide the fact that it can use matched text from the search (capture groups) in the replace term. Such a powerful feature surely deserves more than a very obscure inference to this ability. Ah well, now I know. And I wrote pointless software last night for a custom search and replace! LOL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-breaking parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712716/non-breaking-parentheses)

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of others trying to solve similar sticky problems, have a look at the available "special" space characters. These are the pages on wikipedia I checked out:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29
and 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner
There's also the "thinspace" and the "hairspace", in case you're looking for a "space" that is narrower in size than the regular space.

Answer (score 1):

There is no CSS solution that does not require changes to the markup or content. The reason is that there is no element to attach CSS styles to. CSS has no properties that would control line breaking behavior depending on the characters in content (like “don’t break after ‘]’ characters”); maybe it will some day.

There are several ways to [prevent line breaks](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html), such as the nonstandard but well-supported `nobr` element, the CSS setting `white-space: nowrap` (set on an element inside which automatic line wrapping is to be disabled), and the special character zero-width no-break space (ZWNBSP). While all of these work generally well in modern web browsers, they have problems in ebook readers. You need to analyze which user agents are important and test the various approaches on them. Note that ZWNSP is unsafe in the sense that when not supported (in some ebook readers and in very old web browsers), it creates a problem that is more serious than the one being solved (an odd-looking symbol is shown). The other approaches may fail, but just in the sense of not having any effect.

After choosing the approach, consider whether it can be implemented using client-side JavaScript, i.e. code that runs after the page has loaded and may modify the document tree e.g. by inserting new elements. For example, if the issue is with bracketed expressions and brackets are not used otherwise, the code could just insert a special character after the closing bracket or recognize the next word and wrap the bracket and the word in an element.

Comment: I've just come back from checking out wikipedia and trying out the "zero white space joiner" (&zwj;) and "no break space" (&nbsp;) and a combination of these may do the trick. I just have to hope that other readers will display correctly, as I can test only on the one I have.

Comment: @MaxBrewster, there are observations according to which zero width joiner (ZWJ) is more problematic in ebook readers than ZWNBSP, see http://epubsecrets.com/avoiding-bad-punctuation-breaks-in-ebooks.php