# parenthesis breaks line in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, parentheses

have a similar question here [Non-breaking parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712716/non-breaking-parentheses#)
but the white-space: nowrap; makes the whole thing in one line which is not ideal.
e.g. a group of elephant(s) ... In ie, (s) could be in a separate line. Is there any way to disable this in IE?

Comment: Why not `...a group of <span class='nobreak'>elephant(s)</span>.`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The text is input from customer, very hard to pick up and add a tag for (s) bit.

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunate that Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge behave differently than other browsers in this regard. I am an engineer on the Microsoft Edge team, and will file an interop bug so as to investigate the matter further with the team.

For the time being, you could wrap each of these instances in a span element, preventing white-space wrapping on the contents therein. I understand this content is coming from user-input; as such, you could identify the portions of the user-input that need to be wrapped, and replace them with an element. As a simple example, here is one approach:

```js
var tweets = [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( ".tweet" ) );

tweets.forEach(function ( tweet ) {
    tweet.innerHTML = tweet.innerHTML.replace(/\w+\(\w+\)/g, function ( match ) {
        return "<span class='nobreak'>" + match + "</span>";
    })
});
```

```css
.nobreak {
    color: white;
    background: green;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.tweet {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    animation: rescale 20s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes rescale {
    from { width: 100% }
      to { width: 25%  }
}
```

```html
<p class="tweet">@ericlaw I've been thinking about this feature, and the security risk(s). I like the fact they're experimenting, but wonder at what cost.</p>
```

Comment: This was happening in an email context for me, for Office 365 Internet Explorer (and I suppose Edge), and I had to code the email like so: `<span style="white-space: nowrap;">account(s)</span>`